# External css link not working in IE website page

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I seem to be having an interesting problem linking my css stylesheet. Everything is working perfectly fine on my website css wise for every page on chrome, firefox, and anything else. But for some reason, 1 page in IE is displaying weird. Im using the same stylesheet for almost every page on the website but yet its not working on 1 page on IE.

Check it out for your self on IE. Heres the home page that works fine http://www.sentinelgaming.net

Then on the forums page it messes up. http://www.sentinelgaming.net/forums

Again, im using the same stylesheet on the home page as the forums. But one page displays differently.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the forums page is failing to load this css file:

http://files.enjin.com/202624/general%20files/navbar%20css.css

It might be due to the fact that on line 740 there are second `DOCTYPE`, `html`, `head`, and `body` tags. You should delete all that and move the css file link to the proper `head` tag at the top of the page.

This should hopefully fix your issue.